# Unhandled Rejection (Error): The dtype of dict['ImageTensor'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be int32, but was float32

Tags: reactjs, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I try to run [deep lab](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/08dd2ed9ffcd3f3604026c2374f99a3498184d33/deeplab) model javascript on video  here but I get the error Unhandled Rejection (Error): The dtype of dict['ImageTensor'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be int32, but was float32 , here is my code

```
import React,{useEffect,useRef} from "react";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";

import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs"
import * as deeplab from "@tensorflow-models/deeplab"


 
const Webcamera = () => {
    const webcamref = useRef(null)

    const loadModel = async () => {
        const modelName = 'ade20k';   // set to your preferred model, either `pascal`, `cityscapes` or `ade20k`
        const quantizationBytes = 2;  // either 1, 2 or 4
        const model = await deeplab.load({base: modelName, quantizationBytes});

        

        setInterval(() => {
            detect(model)
        },100)
      };

      const detect = async (model) => {
          if(typeof webcamref.current!=undefined && webcamref.current!=null && webcamref.current.video.readyState === 4 ){
              const video = webcamref.current.video
              const videowidth = webcamref.current.video.videowidth
              const videoheight = webcamref.current.video.videoheight

              webcamref.current.video.videowidth = videowidth
              webcamref.current.video.videoheight = videoheight
              

              model.segment(video)

              
          }
      }

      useEffect(()=>{loadModel()}, []);
      

return <Webcam ref={webcamref}/>
}

export default Webcamera
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was the tensorflow version , do the following:
uninstall current version

```
npm uninstall @tensorflow/tfjs
```

Install lower version 1.3.1

```
npm install @tensorflow/tfjs@1.3.1
```

Deeplab seems to not work on higher version